# Swift closures, closure signatures, and closure equivalence

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm kind of curious why this closure assignment works in Swift 4.1 (not tested yet under Swift 4.2, but both snippets don't work in Swift <= 4.0):

```
func intArrayFunc(_ policy: Int = 0,  completion: (([Int]?, Error?) -> Void)? = nil) {
    print("policy = '\(policy)'")
    completion?([policy + 2], nil)
}

typealias anyArrayClosure = (Int, (([Any]?, Error?) -> Void)?) -> Void

let a: anyArrayClosure = intArrayFunc(_:completion:)

a(1) { (results, error) in
    results?.forEach({ (result) in
        if let oneResult = result as? Int {
            print("\(oneResult) (Should be 3)")
        }
    })
}
```

However, this doesn't:

```
func t1(_ int: Int = 0, array: [Any]? = nil) {
    print("t1")
}

func t3(_ int: Int = 0, array: [Int]? = nil) {
    print("t3")
}

typealias function = (Int, [Any]?) -> Void

let t2: function = t1
let t4: function = t3
```

Or is it a just a bug in the 4.1 compiler?

Comment: Fair enough. However, what's eluding me is that


    `(([Int]?, Error?) -> Void)? `


can be passed as a:

    `(Int, (([Any]?, Error?) -> Void)?`

Answer (score 1):

### Observation 1

```
func t1(_ int: Int = 0, array: [Any]? = nil, completion: ((Int) -> ())) {
    print("t1")
}

func t3(_ int: Int = 0, array: [Any]? = nil, completion: ((Int) -> ())) {
    print("t3")
}

typealias function = (Int, [Int]?, ((Any) -> ())) -> Void

let t2: function = t1
let t4: function = t3
```

This **works** because `t2` and `t4` will take `Int` arguments which are compatible with the `Any` in `t1` and `t3`, but if you do the opposite it won't because, `Int` cannot accept an `Any` value.

---

### Observation 2

Now the closure is again receiving an argument. So if pass an `Int` argument to `Any` it is valid, but if you pass `Any` to an `Int`, it isn't.

So, this **doesn't work**.

```
func t1(_ int: Int = 0, array: [Any]? = nil, completion: ((Int) -> ())) {
    print("t1")
}

func t3(_ int: Int = 0, array: [Any]? = nil, completion: ((Any) -> ())) {
    print("t3")
}

typealias function = (Int, [Int]?, ((Int) -> ())) -> Void

let t2: function = t1
let t4: function = t3
```

---

So ultimately, it boils down to the *simple fact* that **whatever you are passing to a variable should be compatible with it's type**. You can pass and `Int` to `Any` but not vice-versa.

Comment: Yes,  that's what I inferred too! However, is there any (documented) rationale behind the decision to don't do type checking on closures as function parameters?

Comment: @Alfons the same reason i stated? The parameters have already been used inside their methods, so they need to strict on the types, while the closure will only be used later so it can be flexible?